# Cannot connect to *.dbf file through JDBC drivers

Tags: java, jdbc, dbase

i'm trying to connect to *.dbf (dBase III) file on my Java application, running on a Windows Server 2003 system.
I'm encountering this error and I cannot really understand the meaning (sources for OdbcJdbc.java seems to be unavailable):

> [Microsoft][ODBC dBase driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path error

This is the code I run on my application:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

String database = "jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft dBase Driver(*.dbf)};DBQ=D:\\dbNeri\\CARISTAT;";

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database);

Statement s = conn.createStatement();
String selTable = "SELECT * FROM CARISTAT";
```

Does it exists a JDBC driver able to connect to dBase files or do I have to import external libraries to do the magic?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name using single backslash is not really an option: this is a java string after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, I finally found the answer to all my problems.

Without any need to configure a ODBC data source, the mistake in that code was I've targeted directly in my connection string the file name I would like to access.
(In the code up here, I removed "\CARISTAT").

Thus the application run easily and with no more JDBC driver error!!

Thanks anyway for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Dbase III is a 16-bit product and Windows Server is a 64-bit environment, which is what causes the compatibility issue.

You will have to use dBDOS to use your DOS based dBase to run our dBase applications on 64-bit platforms.

These sites have more information:

- http://pmcgee@dbasellc.com
- http://www.dbase.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to set up a DSN for that database (using ODBC Administrator)?  Maybe you just don't have the dBase ODBC drivers installed on that server?

Comment: Hi Kevin!
I can try configuring the ODBC data source on my server, can you validate the URL string i'm using to connect?
Just to be sure the problem is just on the data source config..