# 16-bit dBase integration with RESTful API Server

Tags: rest, api-design, progressive-web-apps, 16-bit, dbase

I've been looking all over the web for a solution to a client problem. They refuse to retire their 16-bit dbase database, but still want us to development real-time PWA web applications to read/write to the dbase system.

If it is even possible to get a RESTful API server working with 16-bit dBase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can create a PWA app with dBase or any DB, which has option to communicate to modern programming languages via APIs like JDBC, ODBC. Then that programming language of your choice, say [JAVA talking to dBase via JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274120/cannot-connect-to-dbf-file-through-jdbc-drivers), can expose the functionality via RESTFul service.

For a PWA app, underlying back-end service tech stack is masked over plain HTTP requests. So it doesn't matter what back-end service you use and what DB that talks to in turn, for a PWA

As an update on your “real time “ need, not sure what kind of real-time functionality you are planning and on expecting what ETA/SLA. While no doubt you can build a PWA with any dB as stated above, it can certainly impact its performance. If you need something like googles auto suggest which pulls up results as you type, you need something like “in-memory” DB.

So the question is more of what performance your DB can support and what is expected. I do not see any feasibility challenge with respect to PWA.

Comment: For the real-time portion, we will need auto complete, messaging, notification, user assignments/permissions, and more. At the end of the day, we are really trying to convince the client that it's more work to connect to dbase than its worth... not to mention the limitations on field char sizes. I've thought about 'cloning' the db to NoSql and writing to both through an API but only reading from the NoSQL db—this would also help in the case that the dbase goes down. What are the other downsides to integrate that we could use to justify 'NOT' using dbase and convert the data to NoSQL?

Comment: Performance limitation and storage constraints are good enough to demonstrate what you will get at the end. You can demonstrate your clients with a single table with a single api supplying data to your auto suggest and let them experience the performance. Then tell them factor that to real time use where anticipated number of concurrent users access the DB. If the still need the same DB, good luck to them ;)